# several relationships from a node to another node

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j. I have a .csv file with two columns separated by ",". The first column contains first names and the 2nd column contains the last names:

```
Lname,Fname
Brown,Helen
Right,Eliza
Green,Helen
Pink,Kate
Yellow,Helen
```

I want to create nodes for *Lname* column and nodes for *Fname* column. For the rows that have the same Fname, I want to connect Lname to the corresponding Fname. For example I want to have a "Helen" node that three nodes "Brown", "Green" and "Yellow" connected to "Helen". I also want to connect "Fname" nodes to a "central node". I have written this code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS row
WITH row.Fname AS first, row.Lname AS last
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first})
MERGE (c:central {name: "central node"})
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
RETURN count(o)
```

when I run this code and display the output using this query:

```
MATCH (c:central)-[r:CONTAINS]->(o:fi)-[rel:CONTAINS]->(p:la)
RETURN c, r, o, rel, p
```

I receive this graph as output:
[image: graph]

As you see according to the number of last names, I have the same number of relationships to the first names, For example I have 3 relationships from "central node" to "Helen", but I want only one relationship from "central node" to "Helen". What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in your final `MERGE` clause.

```
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
```

Neo4j will take this entire pattern and ensure it is unique. Since each time it is invoked (due to the last name changing) the whole thing is created. If you would like to have a single relationship from the central to the first name nodes then you need to split it up into two separate parts. Using the following the first `MERGE` will only create the central-first relationship once.

```
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)
MERGE (o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, but can I ask why the colors of all nodes are gray? I want the colors of nodes change based on the labels of the nodes.

Comment: cool. If you look at the top of a particular Neo4j browser pane you will see the labels present there. Click on the one you want and then look at the bottom of that same pane. At the bottom of the pane, you can pick size, colour and atribute for a particular label.

Comment: Isn't it possible to achieve this when we create the nodes automatically? (through the query maybe?)

Comment: you could type `:style reset` in the browser and that will reset the style choices that have been made. you can read more on browser styling here in the docs...
https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling