# Import data from 2 csv files in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As a continue to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187636/several-relationships-from-a-node-to-another-node) in which I completely explained what I'm supposed to do, in case my central node is located in another .csv file, how can I import it in my graph?

The content of names.csv (2 columns: Lname & Fname):

```
Lname,Fname
Brown,Helen
Right,Eliza
Green,Helen
Pink,Kate
Yellow,Helen
```

The content of central.csv (2 columns: central & value):

```
central,value
cent1,10
```

I tried something like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///central.csv' AS frow
MERGE (c:center {name: frow.central})
WITH *
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS srow
WITH srow.Fname AS first, srow.Lname AS last
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first})
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)
MERGE (o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
RETURN count(o)
```

but it didn't work for me. It created the central node for me, but my central node is not connected to *first* nodes as it was supposed to. What's wrong. I wanted it to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show (in your question) the contents of your 2 files?

Comment: @cybersam I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `WITH` clause does not contain `c`, so `c` becomes an unbound variable after that clause.

Change this:

```
WITH srow.Fname AS first, srow.Lname AS last
```

to this:

```
WITH c, srow.Fname AS first, srow.Lname AS last
```

*By the way, your query will only work as you expect if `central.csv` contains just one data row (as it does currently).*